# How to add a landscape layout only for one of the fragments in an activity in Android?

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, fragment, landscape-portrait

I have an activity with many fragments in it. I want to set portrait and landscape orientation to only one of the fragment say fragmentA. I don't want the screen to show other fragments in landscape mode.

So I put the following in manifest file:

```
   <activity
        android:name=".MyMainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize">
    </activity>
```

But this stopped the fragmentA to show in landscape mode.

I have put 2 different layouts for fragmentA i.e. one in layout-land and layout folder.

Answer (score 0):

if you have made your layout using xml under res folder.There you define android screen orientation="potrait".I hope then it will works without affecting other fragments

Comment: its not working and I am not clear on what you wanna say... can you please be a bit more clear on what you are saying.